# Inner join returns too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I a having an issue joining two tables in order to return just one column from the other.

`SELECT om.*, cm.Sales_Stage 
FROM dbo.OM_Table1 om 
 JOIN dbo.Criteria_Matters cm ON cm.clientCorporationID = om.ClientCorporationID
ORDER BY om.ClientCorporationID`

I want to include the Sales_Stage from my CM table but the join causes the result set to return 14k+ rows instead of the ~7k that is returned without the join.

Is there anyway to just bring in this additional column without blowing up the query?

Comment: I mean, that just means that the `dbo.Criteria_Matters` table have more than one row per `clientCorporationID`.

Comment: Help us help you - Please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: Your issue is that you are pulling om.*.....

Comment: Just pull the fields you need and that will likely help you

Comment: Since `dbo.Criteria_Matters` has multiple rows with the same `clientCorporationID`s, the first question to answer is what it means that the query you already have is producing more rows than you expect.  If it is producing duplicate rows, then you could conceivably solve the problem by using `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Otherwise, you need to determine which rows to keep and which to filter out.  We don't have any information about that.

Comment: @logixologist how would that help with op's issue?

Comment: changing `om.*` will not change OPs problem... the issue he has is caused by the fact that `cm.clientCorporationID` has multiple rows.

Comment: @logixologist how can number of columns in the select statement can affect the number of duplicated rows?

Comment: yeah you guys are probably right... my first reaction was to think cartesian product but its a `inner join` so that is not likely the issue.

Comment: Use a CTE and a partition to get the row you want and exclude the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery... note that this may not correctly select the `sales_stage` you want as you have multiple entries in `Criteria_Matters` per `ClientCorporationID`.  You probably need an order by on the subquery.

```
SELECT om.*, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 cm.Sales_Stage 
    FROM dbo.Criteria_Matters cm
    WHERE cm.clientCorporationID = om.ClientCorporationID)  AS Sales_Stage
ORDER BY om.ClientCorporationID
```

... I'm assuming the `om.*` was just for the example.  it is typically best practice to NOT do that in production.

If you intended to see the differences you may want to do something like this instead...

```
SELECT om.*, cm.Sales_Stage, cm.Criteria_MatterID
FROM dbo.OM_Table1 om 
JOIN dbo.Criteria_Matters cm ON cm.clientCorporationID = om.ClientCorporationID
ORDER BY om.ClientCorporationID
```

Comment: Indeed you are right that "this may not correctly select the sales_stage [the OP] want[s]".  In fact, as written, there is no way to be confident that it will produce the desired results unless the extra rows are dupes (in which case `SELECT DISTINCT` might be a better choice).  As such, it's unclear why you present it as an answer.

Comment: Agreed... but that would still expand his list which doesn't seem to be his intent by the question posted.  Though the real answer may be to add the PK from `Criteria_Matters`

Comment: The `SELECT distinct` was a copy and paste error... I removed the `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing since there is no information on the structure of your tables, but the problem is likely that the Criteria_Matters table has many records for a given clientCorporationID. So it will duplicate every record in OM_Table1 based on the number of matching Criteria_Matters.ClientCorporationID records.

There are a few ways to deal with this - one way would be to use an inline view instead of joining to the full Criteria_Matters table.

If you add an inline view and GROUP BY Criteria_Matters.ClientCorporationID - you are guaranteed that there will be only one record per ClientCorporationID in the joined table - and you will not get duplicated records. Of course since you are grouping by clientCorporationID, you need to apply some aggregate function to Sales_Stage. If you just pick MAX(Sales_Stage), you will get whatever the maximum value is. If you know Sales_Stage is the same for every given clientCorporationID - you are all set. The SQL will look something like the following:

```
SELECT om.*, cm.Sales_Stage 
FROM dbo.OM_Table1 om 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT clientCorporationID, MAX(Sales_Stage) AS Sales_Stage
    FROM dbo.Criteria_Matters
    GROUP BY clientCorporationID 
) cm ON cm.clientCorporationID = om.ClientCorporationID
ORDER BY om.ClientCorporationID
```

However, if there are different Sales_Stage values for a given clientCorporationID in the Criteria_Matters table - you can group by both clientCorporationID and Sales_Stage. When you do this, you will now get OM_Table1 records duplicated - but only for each unique Sales_Stage corresponding to a ClientCorporationID in Criteria_Matters. The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT om.*, cm.Sales_Stage 
FROM dbo.OM_Table1 om 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT clientCorporationID, Sales_Stage
    FROM dbo.Criteria_Matters
    GROUP BY clientCorporationID, Sales_Stage
) cm ON cm.clientCorporationID = om.ClientCorporationID
ORDER BY om.ClientCorporationID
```

Good luck!